# Stopped continuous local martingales

Tags: martingales, stopping-times, local-martingales

Suppose we have a continuous local martingale $M$. Then, by definition, there exists a sequence of stopping time $(T_n)$ s.t $T_n\uparrow \infty$ and that the stopped process $M^{T_n}$ is a uniformly integrable martingale

Now suppose we fix $s >0$. Then if $M$ is a continuous local martingale then there will exist some $n$, such that $T_n>s $ a.s.

Since the stopped process $N_t=M_{\min\{t, T_n\}}$ is a martingale, then we can stop it once again to get that $P_t=N_{\min\{t,s\}}$ is a martingale.

But $P_t=M_{\min\{s,t,T_n\}}=M_{\min\{s,t\}}$ as we have $T_n>s$ a.s.

But that means that for a fixed time $s$ stopping the continuous local martingale will result in a martingale.

Similarly, this idea can be generalised to the case when $s$ is bounded.

Is all my reasoning correct? It seems not, because when reading proofs of various statements I came across one which says "Stopped continuous local martingales at fixes times are continuous local martingales" so I'm starting to doubt my reasoning

Comment: "[...] there will exist some $n$, such that $T_n>s$ a.s." Well, no. Note that $n$ depends on $\omega$, i.e. for any $\omega$ you can find $n=n(\omega)$ such that $T_n(\omega)>s$. In general, you won't be able to find some $n$ such that $T_n(\omega)>s$ **for all** $\omega$.

Comment: But in that case how to interpret the $T_n \uparrow \infty $ bit?

Comment: For each fixed $\omega$ we have $T_n(\omega) \uparrow \infty$.... it's simply not converging uniformly (w.r.t. to $\omega$) to infinity.

Comment: Thanks, that was incredibly helpful!